# invite tracker leaderboard problem with embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
const generateEmbed = start => {
  const current = guilds.slice(start, start + users_per_page);
  const tes = start + users_per_page;
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(config.color)
    .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
    .setFooter(`Σελίδα ${Math.floor(start/users_per_page)+1}/${Math.ceil(guilds.length/users_per_page)}`);
  db.set(`leaderboardtset_${message.guild.id}`, start);
  let content = "";

  current.forEach(g => {
    const i = db.add(`leaderboardtset_${message.guild.id}`, 1);
    content += `\`${i}.\` <@!${g.Id}> ${config.invite_right} \`${g.Value}\`\n`;
  });
  const nextPageStart = start + users_per_page;
  if (nextPageStart >= guilds.length) {
    row.components[1].setDisabled(true);
  }
  embed.setDescription(content);
  return embed;
};
```

Total 5 users have make invites
I set every page has 3 users 1. #1user #2user #3user
but when i go to the next page (page 2)
show me again user #3 from page one and extra user#4 and user#5

also footer still 1/2 and not 2/2

i want help can someone tell me how to fix this ?
i want in next page show only number 4 and number 5 don't get number 3 from page 1

anyone who has time and can help me immediately would appreciate it